# Photogrammetry, Width and height ratio of rectangle in image

Tags: aspect-ratio, photogrammetry

How do I get the width and height ratio of a sheet of paper (or some other rectangular thing) from an image? Here is an example/image that maybe makes my question a bit clearer, https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TcJn.jpg . I know the coordinates of the corners of the paper in the image. I guess it is impossible to get the true width and height of the paper, but it should be possible to get the width and height ratio of the paper, right?

Comment: Assuming all 4 corners of the paper are 90 degree angles, then yes, you should be able to get a ratio.  Is there a formula you have tried so far?

Comment: @NeilN No, I am looking for a formula, but cant seem to find one. I have tried to derive one by myself, but with no luck. Was hoping someone here would be able to do it or give me any suggestions....